# SwiftUI wait for completion function before returning

Tags: swift

I have this swift code:

```
   private func checkPhoneNumber(number: String,completion: @escaping (Result<Int, Error>) -> Void) -> () {
        self.db.collection("customers").whereField("telephone", isEqualTo: number).getDocuments() { (querysnapshot,err) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(.success(querysnapshot!.documents.count))
           }
        }
    }


@State private var ret = true

    private func validateIns(phone:String) -> Bool{

checkPhoneNumber(number: phone, completion: { documentCount in
            if documentCount>0{
                self.ret = false;
            }
        })
        return self.ret
    }
```

I want my `checkPhoneNumber` to first get data from firebase and then `validateIns` to return, based on the data from firebase. However, since firebase takes 1-2 seconds, `self.net` always returns true, despite the documentCount value. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the checknumber function is dispatched async it is not perfomred in order on the main queue. Essentially this means whille your program is waiting for the result of the database query it runs the rest of the code, so this:

```swift
@State private var ret = true
```

will always be true. Maybe by turning the order around you can get the result you need. Something along the lines of this might work, depending on how the funcs are used in the rest of your code.

```swift
   private func checkPhoneNumber(number: String,completion: @escaping (Result<Bool, Error>) -> Void) -> () {
        self.db.collection("customers").whereField("telephone", isEqualTo: number).getDocuments() { (querysnapshot,err) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //##check doc count then move forward##
                if completion(.success(querysnapshot!.documents.count)) > 0 {
                   self.ret = false
                }
           return self.ret
        }
    }
```